# Java - Storing UTF-8 characters (specifically Russian characters) in mysql database using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8

Using a prepared statement I am trying to store Russian characters in a field on a particular tables. The table and field is using the utf8 character set and utf8_bin collation.

If I manually run an insert via an IDE or command line, the string saves as expected.

```
INSERT INTO utf8Table VALUES('Анатолий Солоницын');
```

I am then able to query that table and can get back the expected String as well.

The Connection is setup through a resource in tomcat's context.xml file with the following config:

```
<Resource 
    name="jdbc/DoolliDB"  
        auth="Container"   
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"   
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        useUnicode="true"
        characterEncoding="UTF8"
        ....
</Resource>
```

As I said, I am able to read the string/characters just fine, so I assume that both the table and the connection settings are set properly.

I am using a PreparedStatement/CallableStatement in the following way:

```
CallableStatement callableStmt = __mySqlConnector.getConnection().prepareCall("INSERT INTO utf8Table VALUES(?)");

callableStmt.setString(1, "Анатолий Солоницын");

callableStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Instead of Анатолий Солоницын, what is getting inserted into the database is: ???????? ?????????

> Also note that "normal" utf-8 strings, such as über, are getting saved
>   properly.

Both

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

and

```
java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().name()
```

are also both returning UTF-8.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what character encoding are you using to compile your source files?

Comment: Good thought - I added encoding="UTF-8" to the javac portion of my ant build file and still not joy.

Comment: are those characters _written_ in your source file as utf8?  (i.e. the version you feed to javac must match how the bytes are actually written).

Comment: They are not actually stored in the source file. I just simplified the code to demonstrate the issue. It is actually being inputted from the user. I have done various printouts throughout the execution of the code (and viewing tomcat's catalina.out log) and can definitely confirm that the String being used in the setString is the appropriate Анатолий Солоницын.

Comment: Slightly OOT, but why do you use `CallableStatement` to execute the `INSERT` in DB? Shouldn't you use `PreparedStatement` instead?

Comment: PreparedStatement is an interface. CallableStatement implements that interface. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define the connection encoding in the database url, not in the attribute.

```
<Resource 
    name="jdbc/DoolliDB"  
        auth="Container"   
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"   
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        ...
</Resource>
```

Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

> Warning Do not issue the query 'set names' with Connector/J, as the
>   driver will not detect that the character set has changed, and will
>   continue to use the character set detected during the initial
>   connection setup.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it was going to be something simple but I was pulling my hair over here trying to figure out what it was. Everything working now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 sql statement I use in PHP, maybe they will help here:

- set character_set_results=utf8
- set character_set_connection=utf8
- set character_set_client=utf8

For example:

```
CallableStatement callableStmt = __mySqlConnector.getConnection().prepareCall("set character_set_results=utf8");
```

Comment: Tried setting SET NAMES 'utf8' (according to mysql doc here is does the same thing http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) and same result.